# javascript .keyup correct price formatting and more

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

So far I have this which is comprised of snippets. I am not an expert in JavaScript by far so if anyone could help me achieve the following I would be very grateful and hopefully learn something new today :)

I want to achieve the following:

When a user types 1000000 into the input field the results shown are as follows,

1. Higher than $1 million
2. Lower than $1 million
3. Between $970 thousand and $1.3 million

Currently I can achieve the correct display of digits to prices but don't know how to add the word million, thousand, hundred to the end of the prices. Plus I'm not sure how to subtract 3% and add 3% to the price for the between price part.

Here is my code so far:

```
<input type="text" id="price" class="liveprice" value="<?php echo $myprice; ?>" >   
<p>Higher than <span id="higher"><?php echo $myprice;?></span></p>
<p>Lower than <span id="lower"><?php echo $myprice;?></span></p> 
<p>In between <span id="between"><?php echo $myprice;?></span></p> 

<script type="text/javascript">
// make sure it adds commas and dots to price
$.fn.digits = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
    })
}

// update in real time
$("input.liveprice").keyup(function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

    $("#higher").text(value).digits();
    $("#lower").text(value).digits();
    $("#between").text(value).digits();

}).keyup();
</script>
```

Comment: @samuel i have updated my question. removed the .00 cents to make things more clear. I want user to input 1000000 and in return get 1,000,000 million or if they input 970000 they get $970,000 thousand

Comment: The word "million" is redundant.

Comment: It's not redundant, it's wrong (like Samuel Liew said). Unless you remove all the zeros and change "$1,000,000.00" to "$1 million".

Comment: @samuel Sorry silly me! i want the user to insert nothing but digits and those digits have a trailing word eg: 500000 would show up as $500 thousand

Comment: @samuel $970 thousand is what im after

Comment: @all have updated my question again! sorry peoples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know if it is higher than 1 million, divide the number by 1 million and then round the number using `Math.floor()`. If the answer is higher than zero then that is "how many million" you have. You can then insert the word million using something like (you'll need to add some stuff here):

```
var val = $('your input').val()/1000000;
if (Math.floor(val) > 0) {
    $('your element with words').text( val + " million" );
}
```

Do the same for 1000 but just divide by 1000 instead of 1000000.

Comment: Thank you simon i will experiment with your advice.

Comment: Cheers mate. With some tweaking i got it to work, i have now learned about math floor. You are the only one that actually offered adivce where the others just made comments about how wrong my question was. appreciate your help :)